# Joining two tables using the LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join two tables based on two values being alike. I have this so far but I'm getting a SQL error as soon as I use the `%`.

```
SELECT downloads.d_key, payer_email
FROM    paypal_log
INNER JOIN
        downloads
ON      downloads.d_key LIKE "%" + paypal_log.custom + "%"
```

The `downloads.d_key` will be within the `paypal_log.custom`.

Comment: I don't think `LIKE` was intended to be used in this way. It should be used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This appears to have already been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like

Comment: is there a way to parse the key out of `paypal_log.custom`?  If d_key were 11, it could potentially find other keys of 111, 1111, etc... it's not a good way to join.

Comment: @JamesPiggot thanks for that link to the question it worked perfectly.  Maybe posting it here again will help? Other options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql join query using like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 'one' + 'two' FROM DUAL
```

and see what you get.  You'll want to use

```
LIKE concat('%', paypal_log.custom, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL concatenation operator is `||`. You can also use the `CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT downloads.d_key, payer_email
FROM    paypal_log
INNER JOIN
        downloads
ON      downloads.d_key LIKE '%' || paypal_log.custom || '%' ;
```

As others pointed, you are probably doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: Very, very, very, very wrong.  But it *should* run (and run, and run, and run. . .)