# SQL Join on a column LIKE another column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql join query using like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like)

I want to do a join where one column contains a string from another table's column:

```
SELECT
a.first_name,
b.age
FROM names a
JOIN ages b
ON b.full_name LIKE '%a.first_name%'
```

Is this possible? I'm using MySQL. Of course the above query will not work since the LIKE '%a.first_name%' will just look for the string a.first_name, and not the column's actual value.

Comment: If you have a % at the beginning of the string, it will not be able to use whatever indexes you have on that b.full_name column. Just letting you know that your performance will be terrible if you have a sizable database here.

Comment: You'll get what you ask for though.  so if first name is Jo, you'll get josephine, josiline, jobob, jody, joseph etc..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You only need to concatenate the strings, you could also do a search and replace.

```
SELECT
    a.first_name,
    b.age
FROM names a
JOIN ages b
ON b.full_name LIKE '%' + a.first_name + '%'
```

Comment: Works better for me using `ON b.full_name LIKE CONCAT('%', a.first_name, '%')`

Comment: This solution is for SQL Server, not MYSQL

Answer (score 33):

You can use CONCAT:

```
SELECT
  a.first_name,
  b.age
FROM
  names a JOIN ages b
    ON b.full_name LIKE CONCAT('%', a.first_name, '%')
```

or also [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate), that returns the position of the first occurrence of `a.first_name` in `b.full_name`:

```
SELECT
  a.first_name,
  b.age
FROM
  names a JOIN ages b
  ON LOCATE(a.first_name, b.full_name)
```

if there's a match, the join will succeed.

Comment: LOCATE() is interesting, will that just return a non-zero value when the string exists in b.full_name, and return false otherwise?

Comment: @DonnyP locate will return 0 if there's no match, or the position of the first occurrence of first name. 0 is considered equivalent to False, if value is >=1 it is considered True