# How can I check that the data in one column doesn't exist in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Name with 4  columns:

```
ID|Forename|MiddleName|Surname
```

I want to pull out any rows which have the Forename somewhere in the MiddleName

E.g.

```
1|John|John|Smith
```

which I can do with `select * from Name where Forename = MiddleName`

but what I would like to do is pull out rows where the Forename is **somewhere** in the MiddleName

e.g.

```
2|John|John Michael|Smith
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Try `select * from Name where Middlename LIKE '%'+ForeName+'%'`.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed. I couldn't figure out the syntax of where to put in the %s!  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do things like this with the `LIKE` operator.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp
Here are very similar questions: [SQL Join on a column LIKE another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696793/sql-join-on-a-column-like-another-column/14696806), [MySQL join query using like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like)
The solution is:
`SELECT * FROM Name WHERE MiddleName LIKE '%' + Forename + '%'`
or:
`SELECT * FROM Name WHERE MiddleName LIKE CONCAT('%', Forename, '%')`

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed. I couldn't figure out the syntax of where to put in the %s! Really appreciate it.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that SQLite doesn’t support `CONCAT`.