# how to use like operator in join operation

Tags: mysql

how to use like operator in join operation? because i want to join the two table and search the any word of value in table.
my query is

```
select a.*,b.* from table1 a,table2 b 
where columnname 'like %abc%'
```

Comment: `columnname like '%abc%' `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql join query using like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `like` keywords in quotes.

Change:

```
 columnname 'like %abc%'
```

To:

```
columnname like '%abc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.*,b.* 
from table1 a,table2 b 
where (a.acolumnname LIKE '%abc%') OR
      (b.bcolumnname LIKE '%abc%')
```

Comment: @Radhey Why did you unaccept the answer after 2 weeks?