# Join two tables and update based upon equal and like condition, Need to cater in the expansion as well

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables.

**table 1**

```
A   B      C
=================   
1  AAA   AA;BB
2  BBB   CC;DD
3  CCC   FF;G
4  DDD   E
```

**table 2** (this table is expanded based upon columns C in above table which has ";" seperated values, these are expanded in terms of seperate rows)

```
A    B    C   is_valid
11   AAA  AA     0
12   AAA  BB     0
14   AAA  CC     0
```

Below table is formed by checking if the expansion is correct and is_valid flag is raised to 1. So checking needs to be done - Columns B should be exactly same in both the tables and part of column C present in table2 should be available with the same Column B value combination in table1.

**Expected table 2 after update query**

```
A    B    C   is_valid
11   AAA  AA     1
12   AAA  BB     1
14   AAA  CC     0
17   DDD  E      1
```

Need to get help on formation of the update query for updating the is_valid column in table2.

Comment: there are 3 of dbms's in your tag list. Which one is yours?

Comment: Tag properly!!!!!  MySQL <> Oracle <> SQL Server!!!  Which one are you using???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql join query using like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate a like condition where the comparison is another column, you append the wildcard `%` to either end of the column and apply like as normal, I would do this in your where clause however, not the join, like this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.isValid = 1
FROM table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.B = t2.B
WHERE t1.C LIKE '%'+t2.C+'%'
```

Though you could have it as part of the join on like this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.isValid = 1
FROM table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.B = t2.B AND t1.C LIKE '%'+t2.C+'%'
```

UPDATE

you should use `CONCAT('%',t2.C,'%')` over `'%'+t2.C+'%'` as concat will work on more DBMS systems.

Comment: Worth nothing that not all solutions work with all dbms, and you went a little tag happy there. MySQL, SQL-Server and Oracle all have different syntax. This would work on SQL-Server, but I make no guarantees for the other two.

Comment: Don't post answer when you don't know which dbms the OP uses.  This will work in SQL Server, but not the other two.

Comment: @Eric Apparently Vinay uses SQL-Server