# Find all rows with a column where the ending matches a column of another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Okay I have table: ad-domains with one column and I want to find all rows in another table called history with 3 columns: key, domain, time.

I want to do something akin to

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE domain LIKE "%{ALL_DOMAIN_COLUMN_FROM_ad-domains_TABLE}"
```

Is this possible?

**Some Data for an example:**

*ad-domain:*

```
domain
------
ads.com
moreads.com
gottahaveads.com
```

*history:*

```
key      domain
-----------------------------------
1        google.com
2        subads.ads.com
3        gmail.com
4        moreads.com
5        whoa.moreads.com
6        000.hi.whoa.moreads.com
7        ads.com.taco
```

The result should be

```
key      domain
------------------------------------
2        subads.ads.com
4        moreads.com
5        whoa.moreads.com
6        000.hi.whoa.moreads.com
```

Comment: You will need to `JOIN` the two tables on `LIKE` condition. If there could be more than one match, then you will need to `DISTINCT` the result. Or, if you are not allowed to use `JOIN` you can have `WHERE EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're looking for is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM history
INNER JOIN ad-domain ON history.domain LIKE CONCAT('%', ad-domain.domain, '%')
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like) is more information on the topic.

Comment: Hmm never occurred to me to use a LIKE on a join condition. This does it(pretty much, just had to drop the first '%' in the concat statement). Although this is going to take an insane amount of time to run on a 2GB table I'd imagine.