# Mysql LEFT JOIN IN from a varchar field

Tags: mysql

I Have a table with a table with a field containing ids and want make a `LEFT JOIN ON id IN`

table a

```
|id|invoice|contents|
|1 |123    |1,3     |
```

table b

```
|id|content|
|1 |aaa    |
|2 |bbb    |
|3 |ccc    |

SELECT invoice, content
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id IN (a.contents)
```

The result is only 1 row with the first "content.id" an not two rows.
mysql converts the string to a number, right?
How to solve this?

Comment: A `like` statement might help, you could do something such as; `SELECT invoice, content FROM a RIGHT INNER JOIN b ON a.contents LIKE CONCAT( '%', a.id, '%' )`. I do NOT reccomend this (see comment below from Jens as to why) but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like) should help with the like part

Comment: Do not store foreign keys as csv. Read about normalization

Comment: `.. JOIN .. ON FIND_IN_SET(content, contents) ..`